# Whats error focus() on firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

My application function normality on chrome and iexplorer, but not in firefox.

I want him to return to the input if he does not answer the request.

Code example:

```js
$('#txtTime').blur(function() {
  var days = parseInt($('#txtTime').val());
  if (days < 1 || days > 90) {
    $('#msg_days').html('* Entry value > 0 and < 90').css('color', 'red');
    $('#msg_date').html('');
    $('#txtTime').focus();
    console.log(days);
  } else {
    var hj = new Date();
    var prazo = new Date(hj.setDate(hj.getDate() + days));
    $('#msg_days').html('Previsão ').css('color', 'black');
    $('#msg_date').html(prazo.toLocaleDateString());
  }
});
```

```css
.input {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Prazo: 
<input class="input" type="number" min="1" max="90" id="txtTime" name="txtTime" value="45">
</label>
<span id="msg_days"></span><span id="msg_date"></span>
<br><br>
<label>Próximo: 
<input class="input" type="text" id="txtProx" name="txtProx">
</label>
```

Comment: It appears in firefox, clicking the arrows does not set the focus on the field.  If you change it with the arrows, click the input box and then out of it, it updates the value in firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

> switching

```
$('#txtTime').focus();
```

> per

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#txtTime").focus();
}, 0);
```

```js
$('#txtTime').blur(function() {
  var days = parseInt($('#txtTime').val());
  if (days < 1 || days > 90) {
    $('#msg_days').html('* Entry value > 0 and < 90').css('color', 'red');
    $('#msg_date').html('');
    setTimeout(function() {
    $("#txtTime").focus();
    }, 0);
    console.log(days);
  } else {
    var hj = new Date();
    var prazo = new Date(hj.setDate(hj.getDate() + days));
    $('#msg_days').html('Previsão ').css('color', 'black');
    $('#msg_date').html(prazo.toLocaleDateString());
  }
});
```

```css
.input {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Prazo: 
<input class="input" type="number" min="1" max="90" id="txtTime" name="txtTime" value="45">
</label>
<span id="msg_days"></span><span id="msg_date"></span>
<br><br>
<label>Próximo: 
<input class="input" type="text" id="txtProx" name="txtProx">
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Forcing a focus on input seems to make this work in firefox.

```js
$('#txtTime').blur(function() {
  var days = parseInt($('#txtTime').val());
  if (days < 1 || days > 90) {
    $('#msg_days').html('* Entry value > 0 and < 90').css('color', 'red');
    $('#msg_date').html('');
    $('#txtTime').focus();
    console.log(days);
  } else {
    var hj = new Date();
    var prazo = new Date(hj.setDate(hj.getDate() + days));
    $('#msg_days').html('Previsão ').css('color', 'black');
    $('#msg_date').html(prazo.toLocaleDateString());
  }
}).on('input', function(e) {
  $(e.target).focus();
});
```

```css
.input {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Prazo: 
<input class="input" type="number" min="1" max="90" id="txtTime" name="txtTime" value="45">
</label>
<span id="msg_days"></span><span id="msg_date"></span>
<br><br>
<label>Próximo: 
<input class="input" type="text" id="txtProx" name="txtProx">
</label>
```